# Frank copula parameter minimization

Tags: r, optimization, closures

I am attempting to calculate the Frank copula parameter given Kendall's tau. Here is the problem I am attempting to solve numerically in R:

[image: Copula parameter by Kendall's tau]

So far, this is the code I have:

```
copula <- function(tau, method = c("clayton", "gumbel", "frank")){
  if(method == "clayton"){
    tmp <- (2*tau)/(1-tau)
  } else if(method == "gumbel"){
    tmp <- 1/(1-tau)
  } else if(method == "frank"){
    integrand <- function(t) {t/(exp(t)-1)}
    frank_fn <- function(theta) {(((tau - 1)/4) - (((integrate(integrand, 0, theta)[1]/theta) - 1)/theta))^2}
    tmp <- optim(frank_fn, 4, method = "BFGS")
  } else{
    tmp <- "Error: Choice of method is undefined."
  }
  return(tmp)
}
```

This function works for clayton and gumbel but not frank. It throws the following error:

```
Error in optim(frank_fn, 4, method = "BFGS") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

Can someone help shed light on what is wrong with my code? I am fairly new to numerical optimization problems in R.

UPDATE:

The correct code is as follows:

```
copula <- function(tau, method = c("clayton", "gumbel", "frank")){
  if(method == "clayton"){
    tmp <- (2*tau)/(1-tau)
  } else if(method == "gumbel"){
    tmp <- 1/(1-tau)
  } else if(method == "frank"){
    integrand <- function(t) {t/(exp(t)-1)}
    frank_fn <- function(theta) {(((tau - 1)/4) - ((((integrate(integrand, 0, theta)$value)/theta) - 1)/theta))^2}
    tmp <- optim(4, frank_fn, method = "BFGS")
  } else{
    tmp <- "Error: Choice of method is undefined."
  }
  return(tmp)
}
```

Comment: Here is the correct code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need a $value on the integration?

```
copula <- function(tau, method = c("clayton", "gumbel", "frank")){
  if(method == "clayton"){
    tmp <- (2*tau)/(1-tau)
  } else if(method == "gumbel"){
    tmp <- 1/(1-tau)
  } else if(method == "frank"){
    integrand <- function(t) {t/(exp(t)-1)}
    frank_fn <- function(theta) {(((tau - 1)/4) - (((integrate(integrand, 0, theta)[1]/theta)$value - 1)/theta))^2}
    tmp <- optim(frank_fn, 4, method = "BFGS")
  } else{
    tmp <- "Error: Choice of method is undefined."
  }
  return(tmp)
}
copula(30,method='clayton')
```

Comment: Hi @Harlan Nelson. Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually just got the parameters in the `optim()` function mixed up. The intitial guess of `4` should have come before the `frank_fn`. I will be posting the correct code soon.

Comment: so, It appears that you used my $value suggestion, because I see in your code have that now, where you didn't have it before.